# [WinError 10061]Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

Tags: python

Я новичок в python,пишу телеграм бота по урокам Хауди Хо.
Вот ссылка на его урок: https://youtu.be/fp5-XQFr_nk?t=3195.
Вот мой код:

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot ("Токен в исходном коде есть,я убрал его ну на всякий случай.")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

bot.polling( none_stop = True )
```

при запуске бота выдает вышеупомянутую ошибку,что делать.

Answer (score 3):

**Стоит искать причину проблемы, а не спрашивать о ней.** По первой же ссылке Google уже всплывал подобный вопрос. **Дело в блокировки telegram** на территории страны X. То есть вам прямой путь к **VPN, прокси** или что там удобней для вас. Перед тем, как гуглить, переписал код с токеном моего бота. Иии да! Он не запускается без VPN с ошибкой 10061.

```
...
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение', None, 10061, None))
```